# Mystery: SQL query hangs with DataLength() criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a table called Photos. It has a little over 3000 rows and includes an `image` type field called Photo.

This query runs instantaneously:

```
Select PhotoFileName, DATALENGTH(Photo)
From Photos 
Order by DATALENGTH(Photo)
```

This query hangs intermittently (sometimes takes several minutes to complete, then after completing once, runs instantaneously).

```
Select PhotoFileName, DATALENGTH(Photo)
From Photos 
Where DATALENGTH(Photo)>0
```

Same with this query:

```
Select PhotoFileName, DATALENGTH(Photo)
From Photos 
Where Photo is not NULL
```

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: What do the execution plans look like? Output of 'set statistics io on' for slow and fast versions? And when slow query is running any wait types in 'sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks'?

Comment: When the query is taking several minutes, in another query window, check what that session_id is waiting on from sys.dm_exec_requests.

Comment: Perhaps you found a kissing cousin to this "fixed"/"Closed as won't fix" Microsoft Connect item: [Stored procedure with varbinary max write and DATALENGTH runs indefinitely](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/642077/stored-procedure-with-varbinary-max-write-and-datalength-runs-indefinitely#).

Comment: Did you want this mystery cleared up?  If so please provide the info requested above.

Comment: I'm now unable to reproduce the problem myself - after the query runs successfully once (taking several minutes to execute) the problem goes away for a while. I'm trying to figure out how to provoke the problem into reappearing. Very frustrating as you can imagine - we've seen this on our production server, but this was the first time I was able to watch it happening in isolation on my own machine, and now I've lost it again. I suspect once I figure out how to get it in that state again, we'll be halfway to a solution.

Comment: I've had this same problem. I tried prepending 'SET STATISTICS IO ON;' to the query and received this message after the wait: "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *why* you're seeing this problem, but I think you could resolve it by adding a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) to the table to hold the Length of the photo, perhaps tied with an index on that new column.

Comment: Actually there is a computed column `[Photo_DataLength]  AS (isnull(datalength([Photo]),(0))) PERSISTED NOT NULL`. We get the same results whether the criteria refers to `Photo_DataLength` or `DATALENGTH(Photo)`.

Comment: @Herb can you be more specific: when you refer to the computed column in the SELECT list, the where clause, or both? Is the computed column indexed?

Comment: The computed column is not indexed. Having DATALENGTH(Photo) or Photo_DataLength in the SELECT list makes no difference - it's having it in the WHERE clause that causes the query to hang.

Comment: @Herb for kicks, try adding an index to the computed column (maybe even a filtered index). I'm not saying that should necessarily be the solution, but it might provide more info to add to the existing bug HABO pointed out (or a new one).